# importing anything other than youtube_dl in discord.py (preferrably soundcloud)

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm making a native language funny bot for my friends in my server... but I cant make it to play music... and that music ain't in YouTube, so I want to try anything other than YouTube … How to use SoundCloud for my discord bot python??? SoundCloud has it... how to import SoundCloud, pause it, play it, stop it etc. like rhythm bot???... I tried pyglet, but it doesn't play for everyone except me... I also used playsound module, still can't do it...

this is my code(ignore everything except all functions and modules used):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import pyglet
######################################################################

player = pyglet.media.Player()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-")

TOKEN = ""


#######################################################################



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("singam kalayerangidichi!!!")

@client.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send("hi bakthaa!!")

@client.command()
async def swamiji(ctx):
    await ctx.send("kooptiyaa bakthaa?")

@client.command()
async def voicevaa(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()

@client.command()
async def udhavi(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "COMMANDS" , description = "command laam nalla paathu vechiko... ennaala thirumba thirumba solla mudiyaadhu..." , colour = discord.Colour.red())
    embed.add_field(name = "-voicevaa" , value = "edhaa voice channel la nee poitu enna koopadrathukku..." , inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "-kadha" , value = "sukaanubavam kekka use pannu..." , inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "-wait" , value = "pesumbodhu unakku edhaa vela vandhaa, wait nu sollu... " , inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "-ipposollu" , value = "wait pannavechitu apdiye poidaadha... konjam oda vidu..." , inline = True)
    embed.add_field(name = "-niruthu" , value = "kadha pudikala naalo, vera kadha venum naalo, enna niruthu... apram adutha kadha povom..." , inline = True)
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)

    
@client.command()#err
async def kadha(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "SUKAANUBAVAM" , description = "idhula edhaa oru kadhaya choose pannu bakthaa... naa solren..." , colour = discord.Colour.green())
    embed.add_field(name = "KADHA" , value = "\n\n1.arrogant anaconda\n2.raja's revenge" , inline = True)
    embed.set_footer(icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url , text = f"kadha ketta bakthan {ctx.author.name} kaagha naan kudutha badhil...")
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)


@client.command()
async def wait(ctx):
    player.pause()

@client.command()
async def ipposollu(ctx):
    player.play()

@client.command()
async def niruthu(ctx):
    player.next_source()


@client.command()
async def anaconda(ctx):
    player.next_source()
    src0 = pyglet.media.load('aragont anaconda.mp3')
    player.queue(src0)
    player.play()


@client.command()
async def raja2(ctx):
    player.next_source()
    src1 = pyglet.media.load('rajas revenge.mp3')
    player.queue(src1)
    player.play()


@client.command()
async def kelambu(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
    player.next_source()



client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to edit your token out of the post and change the bot's token it in the developer portal immediately

Comment: im gonna do that anyway.. ha ha...